# How to stop beamer from repeating sections using itemize

Tags: beamer, sectioning, itemize

The code below produces a set of beamer presentation frames. The issue is that the section 'a with b', appearing on the right hand side of the theme, repeats with each new item; i.e., adding item<1> and item<2> causes the section name to repeat two times in the sidebar. How is it possible to avoid this behavior so that the section title repeats as many times as I program with the \section function?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
    still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\title{minimal example}
\author{a}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\begin{document}

    \frame{\titlepage}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> a with b
        \item<2> b and c
        \item<3> d
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\centering
    \section{a with b}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1> ab.1
            \item<2> ab.2
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme puts the toc on the side bar. Nothing bizarre here. Section commands should be placed outside frames.

Try

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
    still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}

\title{minimal example}
\author{A.U. Thor}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\section{Name of section 1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \item<1> a with b
        \item<2> b and c
        \item<3> d
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\section{Name of section 2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> ab.1
\item<2> ab.2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```